# Search subfolders for string in files, and delete delete parent folder of matching file

Tags: linux, search, find, xargs

I´ve been searching for quite some time now, but haven´t managed to find a solution to this. I have the following folder structure:

/root/website1/file1.asp 
/root/website2/file2.txt

I would like to search through all folders under /root/ (can be many levels) for files that are no older than 180 days that contain a specific string inside the file. If a file contains the string, it´s parent folder (and the file itself) should be deleted. If file2.txt contained the string, then /root/website2 should be deleted.

I have gotten this far - but am quite stuck with passing dirname {} to an "rm -rf" command on the folder.

find . -name '*asp' -mtime -180 | xargs grep -l 'string' | xargs -I{} dirname {} | rm -rf

In addition, it would be ideal if the search would move to the next folder after finding the first file containing the string - and not continue to search within the same folder. (i.e just return and then delete unique folders, as there could be many matching files in a folder). And lastly, it would be great if I could iterate through a list of strings in an input file to search for.

Essentially, I´m cleaning up a very large amount of injected files on a web server.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -q deleteme {} \; -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u | xargs rm -rf
```

In the command above, find is given three expressions: `-name "*.asp"`,  `-exec grep -q string {} \;` and `-exec dirname {} \;` .   By default, find assumes that these three expressions are connected by `-and` operators.   Find will evaluate the expressions, from left to right, until the outcome is known.   So, if the filename does not match *.asp, it does not run the second expression (because false and anything is false...).   If `grep -q string {} \;` does not return 0, it will not run the third expression.   The third expression prints the dirname of anything that passed the first two expressions.  You then pipe that into `sort -u` to remove duplicates, and `xarg` that to `rm -rf`.

Comment: This command is not worked. however i'm able to print file parent directory if it consist specefic text using this command

Comment: find -type f -exec grep -l "TEXT" {} \; -printf '%h\n'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67046757/remove-parent-directory-if-a-specific-text-contained-file-get-found-inside-it-us