# Delete whole Directory if a Specefic File found in it using Find or Grep Command

Tags: linux, bash, grep, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for Help to Delete whole Directory if a Specefic File found in it using `find` or `grep` Command

I'm able to search a file contained on specefic text using this Command

```
grep -iRl "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W"
```

[image]

As i Found that `index (1).html` file consist this specefic text i have searched.

[image]

Now, Not only I want to remove the `index (1).html` file but also want to remove it's all siblings files created by the hacker and its **parent folder** which is `/uixuqkbxmy/`and `/trwzqrpaaq/` in my case.

for that purpose, I have created and search many commands like below but all goes in vain not worked.

**1. Search file Using `find` and `grep` command Together**

> ```
> find -type f -exec grep -l "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" {} \;
> ```

it only helped me to find the filename and it's path.

**2. Search and Delete**

> find -type f -exec grep -l "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" {} ;  xargs rm -rf

> find -type f -exec grep -l "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" {} ;  -delete

these commands only helped me to delete a specific file that is being searched.

**3. These commands helped me to Print Parent Directory Name.**

> find -type f -exec grep -l "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" {} ; -printf '%h\n'

Now I'm looking for a Solution a Command something like this below

> find -type f -exec grep -l "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" {} ; -printf '%h\n'
> -exec rm -rf "{}" ;

1. It Should search a File that contained Specefic Text inside.
2. It should delete this file including it's sibling files and it's parent directory

Comment: Please don't use images but instead paste the text you imaged.

Comment: While removal of the undesirable directory may appear to be what you want I'd strongly suggest taking the box off-line, restore the last known good backup, patch that to the latest levels available and bring it back online **after** that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
grep -ril "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" | awk -F/ '{$NF="";print}' OFS='/' | xargs rm -rf
```

Seems to work for me:

```
$ mkdir -p public_html/wp-content/plugins/{awerwear,asdfse3r,sdfgeh}
$ vim public_html/wp-content/plugins/{awerwear,asdfse3r,sdfgeh}/index\ \(1\).html
$ grep -ril "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W"
public_html/wp-content/plugins/sdfgeh/index (1).html
public_html/wp-content/plugins/asdfse3r/index (1).html
public_html/wp-content/plugins/awerwear/index (1).html
$ grep -ril "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" | awk -F/ '{$NF="";print}' OFS='/'
public_html/wp-content/plugins/sdfgeh/
public_html/wp-content/plugins/asdfse3r/
public_html/wp-content/plugins/awerwear/
$ grep -ril "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" | awk -F/ '{$NF="";print}' OFS='/' | xargs rm -rf 
$ find
.
./pines
./public_html
./public_html/wp-content
./public_html/wp-content/plugins
```

P.S.: This does **not** invalidate my comment on your question; you will **not** be safe or "unhacked" by just removing those

Comment: Now given this Error Again

Comment: rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘/’
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe

Comment: Does `/` feature in the output of  `grep -ril "Hacked by Hun73rCL4W" | awk -F/ '{$NF="";print}' OFS='/'`?  If so you have a problem ...

Comment: should I try after Removing ** OFS='/' ** from command

Comment: No, that would make the path useless. Please put the output of the grep above into your question as text (not as a screenshot).

Comment: I'm not sure in few directories it working fine, but when I RUN this command on my whole server it continues for sometime but after some time get server logout without effecting anything